# How to calculate the centripetal force along a cartesian axis?

Tags: dynamics

If a centrifuge without a ballast is centered on the origin of an x-y coordinate plane, and starts at the x-axis rotating with increasing velocity counter-clockwise around the origin, how can the centripetal force of this accelerating centrifuge be calculated in the x-direction, and in the y-direction separately? This is to mathematically understand the "knocking" that is happening in an unbalanced centrifuge.

My attempt: Look up a polar function for a spiral as the centripital force is radial, then convert to cartesian coordinates and integrate dy or dx. Attempted this but ran into the problem that for a spiral there are multiple arms of the spiral for each x or y coordinate.

Comment: There is only one centrifugal force so don't you just calculate it, and then along with the RPM project it onto the X and Y-axis? Could also be done in a single step with vectors but same idea.  So if you look at it from the side of the X-Y plane, depending on whether you were looking parallel to the X or Y, you would see the unbalanced mass oscillate in 2 dimensions along the other axis. I don't think it would look like anything special though: two sinusoids 90 degrees out of phase with a frequency matching the RPM with peaks equal to the centrigufal force.

Comment: @DKNguyen There is one continuously increasing centrifugal force as the centrifuge is accelerating.

Comment: Well if you have a time varying RPM then you need to do a vector projection and it sounds like you are already on that road. But what do you mean by "*What do you mean by "Attempted this but ran into the problem that for a spiral there are multiple arms of the spiral for each x or y coordinate.*" Why can't the function for each X and Y axis just track the center of gravity? Otherwise I guess you would need a function for each point along the rotating circle you were tracking.

Comment: As the centrifuge accelerates the centripetal force increases the way a spiral does.

Comment: The spiral is the problem. At any time t the centripetal force is m*r*w^2, along the arm. the arm is at an angle theta to the x axis so the x component is x cos(theta) and theta =integral w dt

Comment: so the x component is m*r*w^2* cos(theta) and theta =integral w dt

Comment: @GregLocock I get the mrw^2 and shouldn't the the x component should be r cos(theta)? I am trying to understand how theta = integral w dt.  Please provide some context for this last equation so I might understand it better.

Comment: That's just integrating the angular velocity to get the the angle. I can see no error in my equations in the last comment

Answer (score 1):

let's say your centripetal vector is rotating with an angular speed of
$$\omega= \alpha t $$

- $\alpha =$ angular acceleration

Let's say the instantaneous x and y of the vector on a frame aligned with the vector and rotating with it are
$$x=\frac{mv^2_{instant}}{r_{instant}}\quad y=0$$

Then the projection of this vector to our stationary cartesian coordinates is
$$X_1= x cos(ωt) + y sin(ωt)= x cos(ωt) +0=x cos(ωt)$$
$$Y_1= -x sin(ωt) + y cos(ωt) = -x sin(ωt) +0= -x sin(ωt)$$

Comment: @Dale, plugin initial values and $ cos(\alpha t^2) $ and integrate.